Not enough space to reinstall MacOS after the encrypted disk loop
So for the last year and a bit my Intel MacBook Pro has multiple times gone into the “enter a password to unlock the disk Macintosh HD” loop.
I learned to solve this by going into internet recovery mode and reinstalling MacOS.
Now the big problem is I don’t have enough free space to reinstall MacOS now. What do I do?
Note: I have a windows bootcamp partition which if cleared into Macintosh HD would give me more than enough space. But I don’t know how to remove it without bootcamp assistant, which I can’t access as I can’t get onto MacOS/Macintosh.
